# How can I call chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab in an extension without asking for <all_urls> permission?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension and I want to take a screenshot of the tab in which the extension is running. The extension url is like "chrome-extension://abcde". Everything works if I include "tabs" and "`<all_urls`>" in my list of permissions, but I don't really want to ask for the `<all_urls`> permission.

I tried adding "chrome-extension://abcde" to permissions instead of `<all_urls`> and I get the error "You do not have permission to use 'tabs.captureVisibleTab'. Be sure to declare in your manifest what permissions you need."

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the hosts you want to be able to capture in the permissions. Now you've set it to your own Extension ID so that's why it's probably not working.

> **captureVisibleTab** - Captures the visible area of the currently active tab in the specified window. You must have host permission for the URL displayed by the tab.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html

Comment: I want permission to capture my extension's screen. What's the host permission for that?If I have both "tabs" and "`<all_urls`>" in regular permissions, it works. If I have them both in optional permissions, I get the "You do not have permission..." error. Isn't that strange?